# Recreate Local Python Environment in Remote Server

Tags: python, conda

I am currently using conda for this purpose.

After generating local environment.yml, I run `$ conda create -n environment.yml` on the remote server.

But this doesn't include global packages that my code references.

I can add a `requirements.txt` using `pipreqs` and then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` remotely but this doesn't take into account dependencies like dlib or boost that a package may need for installation.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two diff type of dependencies. 1) Need to install via apt-get like boost, opencv 2) Need to install via pip.

You need to install apt-get library manually on the server and can define pip related libraries in the requirements.txt file. Because apt-get libraries are environment independent.